# Error when trying to parse through data and find multiple repeated values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

Basically I want to see the position of the start of a sequence of repeated digits. For example, if I have:

```
data_frame <- c(1, 7, 8, 4, 3, 7, 8, 8, 9, 3)
```

and I wanted to find the position at which numbers are greater than 7 3-times in a row, I would want the function to return 5.

```
end_test_machine <- function(distribution_input) { 
for (i in 1:length(distribution_input)){
    if (distribution_input[i] > 7) {
      if(distribution_input[i+1] < 7) {
        end_test_position <- i
        next
      }
    } # End If Statement
    else {
      next
    }
  } # End For Loop
  return(end_test_position)
}
```

When I use the code block above, I always get the error message:

```
Error in if (distribution_input[i+1] > 7) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

How can I compare the next element in the datainput with the current position and return that position if the conditional is true for three consecutive values?

Answer (score 1):

Use `rle`:

```
x <- c(1, 7, 8, 4, 3, 7, 8, 8, 9, 3)

with(rle(x>=7), sum(lengths[seq(which(lengths>3)[1]-1)]))
[1] 5
```